# Phonegap Activity restart fails

Tags: android, cordova

On some devices, restarting my activity fails to work correctly. The old instance of the activity is destroyed, but while the new instance is created (and briefly flickers on the screen), it also ends up being destroyed as well. The reason the activity is restarting is not important but lets say it is because of a device rotation causing a configuration change. This is viewed by our end users as an application crash because the window "goes away" so it's obviously a big deal.

It seems to be related to the way the base PhoneGap activity handles the onDestroy event. I am using an old version of PhoneGap - some of the class names of the PhoneGap classes have changed in the most recent versions.

The sequence of events goes like this (states taken from the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) diagram). I have highlighted a couple of the important events that occur below:

1. Activity instance 1 created
2. Activity instance 1 started
3. Activity instance 1 resumed
4. Configuration change of some kind cause the activity to restart
5. Activity instance 1 paused
6. Activity instance 1 stopped
7. **Activity instance 1 destroyed** (`DroidGap` calls `this.appView.loadUrl("about:blank");`)
8. Activity instance 2 created
9. Activity instance 2 started
10. Activity instance 2 resumed
11. **Activity instance 1 finish** (`DroidGap` calls `finish()`)
12. Activity instance 2 paused
13. Activity instance 2 stopped
14. Activity instance 2 destroyed

At point 7 above, the base class has this in the onDestroy to clean up the WebView:

```
@Override
/**
 * The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. 
 */
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (this.appView != null) {


        // Send destroy event to JavaScript
        this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:try{PhoneGap.onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){};");

        // Load blank page so that JavaScript onunload is called
        this.appView.loadUrl("about:blank");

        // Forward to plugins
        this.pluginManager.onDestroy();
    }
    else {
        this.endActivity();
    }
}
```

At point 11 above, the base class does this in the `onPageFinished` - this runs whenever a url has finished loading, in this case the "about:blank":

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

...

    // Shutdown if blank loaded
    if (url.equals("about:blank")) {
        if (this.ctx.callbackServer != null) {
            this.ctx.callbackServer.destroy();
        }
        this.ctx.endActivity();
    }
}
```

And `endActivity` is just this:

```
/**
 * End this activity by calling finish for activity
 */
public void endActivity() {
    this.activityState = ACTIVITY_EXITING;
    this.finish();
}
```

Logging has shown that when I get to `this.finish()` in `endActivity`, it is running for Activity instance 1, but Activity instance 2 is destroyed. I don't understand why this is.

Answer (score 1):

For people that come to this question with the same problem I had, I found that the issue I was suffering was fixed in the latest phonegap (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2908)